# Filtering lines based on pattern of couple of words

Tags: text-processing

My text file looks like this:

```
city=london&language=en&x=12345&y=6789&z=7
sometext?z=7
city=dublin&language=en&x=12345&y=6789&z=7
city=madrid&language=en&x=12345&y=6789&z=7
sometext?y
sometext?x
```

I need to filter the text by criteria - if certain line contains:

```
city, language, x, y, z anywhere in the line
```

leave this lines.

The output after filtering my data would be:

```
city=london&language=en&x=12345&y=6789&z=7
city=dublin&language=en&x=12345&y=6789&z=7
city=madrid&language=en&x=12345&y=6789&z=7
```

What is the simplest way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can straightforwardly combine regular expression tests logically in `awk` e.g.

```
$ awk '/city/ && /language/ && /x/ && /y/ && /z/' file.txt
city=london&language=en&x=12345&y=6789&z=7
city=dublin&language=en&x=12345&y=6789&z=7
city=madrid&language=en&x=12345&y=6789&z=7
```

Comment: thanks! any idea how to add color to result (highlight city, language, x, y, z)?

Comment: @vayacondios2015 not easily, no - AFAIK you'd need to find the start and length of each match (at least with GNU awk, that should be possible using the `match` function and `RSTART`, `RLENGTH` variables), then insert color codes programatically